# C++11: Is it safe to remove individual elements from std::unordered_map while iterating?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, iterator, unordered-map

Consider the canonical algorithm for removing an element from an associative container while iterating:

```
for (auto iter = myMap.begin(); iter != myMap.end(); )
{
    if (/* removal condition */)
    {
        iter = myMap.erase(iter);
    }
    else
    {
        ++iter;
    }
}
```

I've been applying this algorithm without a second thought when using the C++11 `std::unordered_map` container.  However, after browsing the documentation for `std::unordered_map::erase` on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/erase), I became a little concerned after reading the following note:

> The order of the elements that are not erased is preserved (this makes it possible to erase individual elements while iterating through the container) **(since C++14)**

Based on this statement, I'm assuming there was language added to the C++14 standard to ensure library implementers guarantee ordering after a call to `std::unordered_map::erase`.  For example, maybe such a requirement constrains the implementation from not rehashing the entire container after an element is removed, but rather only allows it to remove the element from its corresponding bucket?

Without such a guarantee in C++11, and if I desire my code to be portable, do I have to worry that some elements will be visited multiple times or not at all if I remove an element from an `std::unordered_map` during iteration?

Comment: Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6442829/241631) which cites the C++11 rules. For erasure from unordered associative containers, only iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. So your code is valid.

Comment: @Praetorian: Thanks for the clarification.  I understand that the iterator is still valid after the erasure, but my concern is that, in light of the C++14 guarantee above, will continuing the iteration until the end yield the same sequence of elements as if I did not remove the element?  If so, do you know why the committee felt that adding the above clarification to C++14 was necessary?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question then. [Here's](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/lwg/issue2356) the issue that brought about the wording change. I think the answer to your question is - *not guaranteed by the standard pre-C++14, guaranteed in practice*. The linked report states as much - *not that any actual implementation does that, anyway*. I'll re-open the question, maybe someone will have a better answer for you.

Comment: @Praetorian: You have a good answer to a good question.  Please put it where I can up vote it. :-)

Comment: @Howard Thank you, but I was hoping someone like you, who has intimate knowledge of at least one std library implementation, would post an answer. Anyway, there's already an answer now that states what I did in my comment.

Comment: ah, that's right: since C++11, `map::erase` returns an iterator. I had the pattern from Effective STL ingrained in memory: `if( ) myMap.erase(it++); else ++it;` but yours is nicer.

Comment: @Praetorian: I agree with Howard and Caladain: your comment is the answer; please add it as such.  The link to Library Working Group issue [2356](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/lwg/issue2356) is what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: **The dangers of NoScript.**  I had noscript running, which displayed the C11 and C14 tabs as one box.  Praetorian's answer is correct about it being guaranteed in practice, and formalized in c14.

** **Below is wrong due to noscript.**

At the bottom of cplusplus it states that

> Only the iterators and references to the elements removed are invalidated.
>
> The rest are unaffected.
>
> The relative order of iteration of the elements not removed by the operation is preserved.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/erase/

At the top of the page, it states it's for C++11...so unless they updated it for C++14, i think it applies to C++11 as well.  Praetorian should put an answer and you should check his for the answer, because even if it's not guaranteed in the standard for C++11 (C++14 being the patch for these sort of things), it's guaranteed in practice.

I couldn't find the STL standard, I seem to have misplaced it, or I'd go see if there was a text guaranteed I could point to. :-/

Comment: Thanks for the additional link, but when I view that page, the statement, _"The relative order of iteration of the elements not removed by the operation is preserved,"_ is listed only under the C++14 tab.  Please correct me if I misread it.  Otherwise, I'd appreciate an edit because I think citing the [cplusplus.com link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/erase/) is useful.

Comment: I had no-script on.  It displayed both tabs as one block of text.  Sorry :-(

Comment: I accepted this answer because it refers to Praetorian's comment above, which is what I was looking for.