# Erasing elements from unordered_map in a loop

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

There are several answers on StackOverflow that suggest that the following loop is a fine way to erase elements from a `std::unordered_map` that satisfy some predicate `pred`:

```
std::unordered_map<...> m;
auto it = m.begin();
while (it != m.end())
{
    if (pred(*it))
        it = m.erase(it);
    else
        ++it;
}
```

I'm specifically interested in C++11 (as opposed to C++14), and the following ominous [note on cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/erase) suggests that the above loop depends on undefined behavior and may not work in C++11 after all:

> The order of the elements that are not erased is preserved (this makes it possible to erase individual elements while iterating through the container) **(since C++14)**

See also [Title 2356. Stability of erasure in unordered associative containers](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/lwg/issue2356) which contains a requested wording change to [Working Draft N3797](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf) item 14 on page 754 (the additional phrase beginning ", and preserve the relative order ...").

> This wording is relative to N3797.
>
> Modify [unord.req], p14 as indicated:
>
> -14- The insert and emplace members shall not affect the validity of references to container elements, but may invalidate all iterators to
>   the container. The erase members shall invalidate only iterators and
>   references to the erased elements, and preserve the relative order of
>   the elements that are not erased.

If my interpretation of the note from cppreference.com is correct, and the above loop depends on undefined behavior in C++11, what's the most efficient way to solve this problem in C++11?

Comment: Usually when a constraint is strengthened like that, it's because all the compilers represented by committee members are already conforming. You're right to be nervous though.

Comment: @MarkRansom Is there a way to be safe? I.e., what's the correct way to do this under the C++11 standard?

Comment: I suspect there *wasn't* a way to be guaranteed safe, thus the change to the standard.

Comment: Found [another SO Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047241/c11-is-it-safe-to-remove-individual-elements-from-stdunordered-map-while-it?rq=1) that links to [Issue 2356](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/lwg/issue2356), which clarifies the bit about all the compilers being conforming.

Comment: Can't you just take repeatedly `mymap.begin()` in a loop and remove it while it is not `mymap.end()`?

Answer (score 19):

To comply with C++11 you're unfortunately a bit limited in how you can tackle this. Your options basically boil down to:

1. Iterate over the `unordered_map` and build a list of keys to delete like so:

   ```
   //std::unordered_map<...> mymap;
   std::vector<decltype(mymap)::key_type> vec;
   for (auto&& i : mymap)
       if (/*compare i*/)
           vec.emplace_back(i.first);
   for (auto&& key : vec)
       mymap.erase(key);
   ```
2. Iterate over the object and reset if we find something to remove - I'd really only recommend this for small datasets. those of you who feel goto is unconditionally bad, well, this option is arguably bad.

   ```
   //std::unordered_map<...> mymap;
   reset:
   for (auto&& i : mymap)
       if (/*compare i*/) {
           mymap.erase(i.first);
           goto reset;
       }
   ```
3. As a somewhat *out there* option, you could also just create a new `unordered_map` and move the elements that you want to keep. This is arguably a good option when you have more to delete than to keep.

   ```
   //std::unordered_map<...> mymap;
   decltype(mymap) newmap;
   for (auto&& i : mymap)
       if (/*i is an element we want*/)
           newmap.emplace(std::move(i));
   mymap.swap(newmap);
   ```

Comment: Yeah, 1 and 3 are the two options I've thought of. I obviously don't like either one of them, but I can't think of anything better.

Comment: require C++14 to compile? ;)

Comment: Maybe in three years. ;-)

Answer (score 9):

Use **erase_if** (c++20) instead of a loop (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/erase_if)

Example for removing odd keys from a map:

```
std::unordered_map<int, char> data {{1, 'a'},{2, 'b'},{3, 'c'},{4, 'd'},
                                    {5, 'e'},{4, 'f'},{5, 'g'},{5, 'g'}};

const auto count = std::erase_if(data, [](const auto& item) {
    auto const& [key, value] = item;
    return (key & 1) == 1;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can always do this:

```
std::unordered_map<...> m;
std::vector<key_type> needs_removing;
for(auto&& pair : m)
{
    if (pred(pair))
        needs_removing.push_back(pair.first);
}
for(auto&& key : needs_removing)
    m.erase(key);
```

It's slower, but the complexity is the same.

Comment: Sure. I guess I'm trying to see if there is a more efficient solution.

Answer (score -4):

Always consult the stl-algorithms first

This one seems to be the wanted:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/

For an overview:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/

**EDIT**
cppreference has an similar example at the bottom of the site.
It works with a c++11 compiler.

Comment: That doesn't work with any associative container. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove

Comment: Similar to what? What example works with C++11 compiler?

Comment: Or rather how do you know that it works with C++11 compiler? And not that the compiler is implicitly using C++14 mode?

Comment: you can choose the compiler version and in parantheses is the standard. i assume this information is correct there.
it works with gcc-4.8, that one has only c++11

Comment: @jonas_toth From the std::remove_if page you linked: `These algorithms cannot be used with associative containers such as std::set and std::map because ForwardIt does not dereference to a MoveAssignable type (the keys in these containers are not modifiable)`. http://ideone.com/5cWOF9 vs http://ideone.com/B7AmNf.

Comment: yes thats right. the looping approach seems to work though

Comment: @jonas_toth so... your answer says that he wants to use remove_if, but you agree that's wrong. Interesting.